# Set content view in android

Tags: android

```
public class CheckitoutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    void change() {
        setContentView(R.layout.someview);
    }
}
```

It does not set the view to someview in the function change. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: You are using small r in `setContentView(r.layout.someview);`...also you can't set content's view multiple times...

Comment: That was a typing error. Have changed it now.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Remove** all other views before setting a new view.
2. Try debugging the program, I am not sure whether the change() is actually (?) being called. If it is not being called than may be, change() is not recognized by android process callback... You can write your code in onResume().... learn more about Activity class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)..As I see change() is not a function in Activity...

   public class Activity extends ApplicationContext {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

   ```
    protected void onStart();

    protected void onRestart();

    protected void onResume();

    protected void onPause();

    protected void onStop();

    protected void onDestroy();
   ```

   }

also use `@Override` with function definitions when you are implementing base class's methods that is a good practice...

Answer (score 2):

you cannot change Activity's layout on the fly, either you have to remove all the views from the activity first and then add new views to the activity or just use some flipper control to change views dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the event of calling the `change()` function after 
`setContentView(R.layout.main);` ,for example:

```
Button changeButton=null; 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    changeButton= this.findViewById(R.id.change_button);
    changeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            change();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The R.java file is being generated by android itself. It's having case-sensitive. like below code

```
void change()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.someview);
}
```

Comment: Do you call the function in somewhere?

Comment: Yes.I have called the function

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything, that is like calling two contentviews in the one oncreate().
Use flipviews